# Defining key binding at one place

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

is it possible to define key bindings at one place in an init file? something like:

```
(define-key-bindings
    '(("C-x M-f" 'fly)
      ("C-x M-k" 'run)
       ...))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are open to installing a package, give [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) (also available on Melpa) a try, which comes with the `bind-key.el` library.

With `use-package` installed, you can do something like below:

```el
(bind-keys
  :map MINOR-MODE-MAP ; if this line is removed, bindings happen in `global-map'
                      ; else they happen in MINOR-MODE-MAP
  ("C-x M-f" . fly)
  ("C-x M-k" . run))
```

There are more variants of `bind-keys` like `bind-key`, `bind-keys*`, `bind-key*` and even `unbind-key`. Check out the documentation in the header of [`bind-key.el`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) to learn more.

The added benefit of using `bind-keys` (and family) is that you can see a summary of all your personal keybindings currently in effect using `M-x describe-personal-keybindings`. That will also tell you if you've overridden a pre-bound key using `bind-keys` (and family).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.

```el
(defun define-key-bindings (bindings &optional keymap)
  (unless keymap (setq keymap  global-map))
  (dolist (bdg  bindings)
    (define-key keymap (kbd (car bdg)) (cadr bdg))))

(define-key-bindings '(("C-x M-f" fly) ("C-x M-k" run)))
```

(Drop the quote marks before the command names - not needed.)