# how to bind a function defined in my .emacs to a key/other command

Tags: key-bindings

It's probably a very basic question, but I am having a hard time finding an answer to it:

I am trying to make emacs look for a makefile somewhere in the parent directories
and use it for compilation.

I found this function:

```
(defun desperately-compile ()
  "Traveling up the path, find a Makefile and `compile'."
  (interactive)
  (when (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (cd (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile"))
    (compile "make -k"))))
```

and put it in my .emacs file, but I can't figure out how to call it.
replacing the compile command doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to bind a key to it.

It would be best to call that function using "M-x compile" or "M-x desperate-compile", but I am open for suggestions.

thanks.

Comment: Does `M-x` `desperately-compile` work?

Comment: it completes as an option but does nothing...

Comment: Then the problem is with the function itself, and binding it to a key won't help.

Comment: There is no problem with your function `desperately-compile`. It seems straight-forward and it does what I think it was intended to do: it runs make in the directory closest in the file tree to the currently opened file. If you need to bind it to a key, then, definitely, `global-set-key` is the way to go. PS. I'll be voting on closing this question because I believe that it shows a lack of effort (the info you are asking for is very easy to find).

Comment: Since this is your first question on this site, it's probably worth looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question/10583#10583 this answer if you want to know about closing questions. That is to say this is not the end of the road, and is not a deliberate attack on a novice user. It is done in good faith that it will encourage you and other site users to better the quality of questions asked here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining key binding at one place](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13846/defining-key-binding-at-one-place)

Comment: @wvxvw: This is *not* a duplicate of [that question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13846/105), IMO. That question (and in particular the answers given to it) has to do with Lisp-coding multiple key bindings. The question here is presumably the very basic question of how to bind a command to a key. (Whether such a basic question should be allowed on the site is another question. I think it should, but I agree that "it shows a lack of effort...".)

Answer (score 3):

Your question: "*I'm not sure how to bind a key to it*", IOW, how do you bind a command to a key?

What did you try?  Did you look in the Emacs manual for how to bind a command to a key?  For example: `C-h r` to get to the Emacs manual, then `i bind TAB` and choose `binding-keys`, to get to node [Rebinding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html). It helps us help you if you tell us what you have already tried.  If you tried using some code to bind the key, show that code, etc.

Anyway, here's an example of how to bind command `desperately-compile` to key `C-o`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'desperately-compile)
```

If you want to see whether your command actually gets invoked when you hit the key you think you've bound to it, try `M-x debug-on-entry RET desperately-compile RET`.

If the command is bound to your key then when you hit your key the debugger will open.  Use `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry RET` to cancel this.

(You can alternatively add a call to function `message` at the beginning of your command code. But as you said that you "found" that code somewhere maybe you don't want to fiddle with it yet.)

Anyway, this is an answer to your question, which is **how to bind a key to a command**.  As to whether your command "works", and if not, why not: please post that as a separate question.

---

(Suggestion: Read some of the Emacs manual. Or follow the Emacs tutorial. You will be glad to have some introductory understanding of things.  And if you are going to be writing Lisp code then check out the manual `Emacs Lisp Intro`, which you can get to by `C-h i`.)

Comment: Whoever: care to say why you downvoted the answer?