# Insert multiple blank line in table editor

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm using the built-in table editor of org-mode.

As described in the documentation, I can use `M-S-Down` to insert a row above my current row. Using the universal argument, I can create my new line below my current line instead of above: `C-u M-S-Down`.

However, when trying to create multiple lines at the same time, it does not work: `C-- C-5 M-S-Down`: this only create one line.

How can I insert a specific number of line below my current line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICS the function org-shiftmetadown is not implemented to handle the numeric prefix argument as a count of actions.

You can use a keyboard macro to use the prefix argument as a count for the number of repetitions.

One recipe which might do what you want goes like this:

```
C-x ( M-S-down C-x )

C-x C-k b F5
```

With the lines above `F5` calls the macro (which does the `M-S-down`.)

The macro can handle numeric prefix arguments.  E.g.

```
C-u 23 F5
```

calls the macro 23 times.

Comment: I don't think either `C-x C-(` or `C-x C-)` is bound by default.

Comment: Ah, a mistake!  Thanks for pointing that out!  I meant `C-x (` and `C-x )`.

Comment: For a one-off, you might not want to waste a keybinding: in that case, skip the `C-x C-k b F5` step and execute the macro 23 times with `C-u 23 C-x e`. Only the most recently defined macro can be executed with `C-x e`.

Comment: By the way, you might want to check out `<f3>` and `<f4>` instead of `C-x (` and `C-x )` (and `<f4>` can also replace `C-x e`). They're not just different bindings, they run slightly different commands you might prefer: `<f3>` starts recording or inserts the macro counter, `<f4>` stops recording or runs the last keyboard macro.

Answer (score 2):

For a handful of rows, I wouldn't bother: pressing `M-S-<down>` a few times is easy. If you are adding rows at the end of the table, pressing `RET` a bunch of times is even easier.

The next step up in complexity is Marco Wahl's macro-based solution.

The next step up is to write your own function which takes a numeric prefix and does the row insertion that many times:

```
(defun n-org-insert-row (n)
   (interactive "p")
   (dotimes (i n) (org-table-insert-row 'below)))
```

You call it like this: `C-u 23 M-x n-org-insert-row`. If you leave out the numeric prefix, `n` defaults to 1. You can also bind the function to a key but I won't go into that here: you can find
out about it elsewhere on this site, e.g. [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14780/how-to-bind-a-function-defined-in-my-emacs-to-a-key-other-command), although there is no substitute for the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings).

In the next step up, you can write a generic "do this n times" function and tell it explicitly when you call it what "this" (the thing that you want to repeat) is:

```
(defun n-do-this (n this)
   (dotimes (i n) (funcall this)))
```

where `this` is a function of no arguments. You can do what you want by evaluating this form:

```
(n-do-this 23 (lambda () (org-table-insert-row 'below)))
```

where you pass in an anonymous function that inserts a row. You can then define `n-org-insert-row` like this:

```
(defun n-org-insert-row (n)
   (interactive "p")
   (n-do-this n (lambda () (org-table-insert-row 'below)))
```

This is a different implementation from the earlier one, but "it looks the same from the outside": it is called the same way and it behaves the same way.

The nice thing about `n-do-this` is that it can be asked to do *anything* n times, not just insert a row in a table.

I'll stop here, but as I hope you can see, the sky's the limit.